# How do I generate metadata for SAML 2?

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have a .Net Core service provider web app using the `ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0` library.

I think I have it 90% working, but I am really very confused about the metadata.  Like where do I get it, or how do I generate it.

So I get this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'uriString')'

```
entityDescriptor.ReadSPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(configuration["Saml2:samlMetadataUrl"]));
```

I know it is referring to this part of my `appSettings.json` file:

```
"samlMetadataUrl": ""
```

Where do I get the metadata file from or how can I generate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your SAML2 Identity Provider should be able to generate the metadata as a file or provide you with a valid url to the metadata. What particular Identity Provider do you use in your Service provider?

Comment: I am using a client's Identity Provider called `SAML Shibboleth`.  But the guy I am working with from that client says I need to provide metadata too for their side.

Comment: That's another issue, the SAML has both client metadata and server metadata. The server's metadata should be accessible without any prior conditions, i.e. tell the guy you first need his metadata. Client's metadata (the part you are supposed to provide) could be generated by hand (an XML text file), just find an example somewhere, fill the text file and ask them to import your metadata from the text file (most identity provider systems can do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You application can generate RP metadata in the [MetadataController](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/MetadataController.cs). Which is handed to the IdP either as a URL or a file.

The IdP then give you the IdP metadata which can be [configured as a URL](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L11) or configured manually.

Comment: Since it's an API Controller, would i need to set up a route URL for it? Like `https://myserver.gov/api/metadata` ?  thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.  I would need to add this to my `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` file, right?  `entityDescriptor.ReadSPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(configuration["Saml2:samlMetadataUrl"]));`

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.